# How to remove the last \n from a file?

Tags: c++

I write a table to a file, using simple:

```
ofstream myfile;

myfile.open("file.txt");


myfile << "rho  P \n";
for (j = 0; j < blocksize; j++) {
    myfile << rho[j] << " " << P[j] << "\n";
    
}

myfile.close();
```

The problem is the last "\n" that creates a new line I don't like. how to remove it?

Comment: do not spam tags. How it is related to C language

Comment: where is `blocksize` defined?

Comment: blocksize is just an integer, equals to 147

Comment: Could you show a [mcve], or a bit more real code w/o syntax errors at least.

Comment: You may not "like" it, but ending _every_ text line in a file with a newline is considered canonical. Thus, `abc\ndef\n` is the preferred way. If you output: `abc\ndef`, then edit the file with `vim`, it will complain with `[noeol]`. If you then do `:wq`,  `vim` will add back the [missing] newline.

Comment: *the last "\n" that creates a new line I don't like* All lines should be ended with `\n`. If you don't like it, it's just your opinion.

Comment: Formally, a text file must end with a newline. This is an artifact of old mainframes with record-oriented file systems, where, apparently, the newline served as a record delimiter for text files.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ofstream myfile; myfile.open(“file.txt”);` to `ofstream myfile(“file.txt”);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ofstream myfile;
    
myfile.open("tabulated/QEOS.txt");
    
    
myfile << "rho (g/cm^-3)    P (GPa); T="<<T<<"\n";
for (j = 0; j < blocksize; j++) {
    myfile << rhoiterp[j] << " " << Piterp[j];
    if(j < blocksize - 1) myfile << "\n";
        
}
    
myfile.close();
```

We are printing "\n" exactly before the last element, we are skipping the last element using a conditinal statement.

Comment: Any explanation?

Comment: We are printing "\n" exactly before the last element, we are skipping the last element using a conditinal statement.